# Why am I having such problems getting latex notation in my gnu plots?

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, gnuplot

I have tried setting the terminal to just about everything under the sun. I got it to read my latex notation for a brief compile and then it decided it didn't want to anymore again. The error that I am getting now is

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `npn-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Though it is there and in the same directory. but I am calling the file like this

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{npn.eps}

\caption{\small blblb}
\end{figure}
```

If I call it like this

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\input{npn}

\caption{\small blblbl}
\end{figure}
```

Them I get an error like this

> LaTeX Error: File `npn.pdf' not found.

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot << TOEND
# Set the output file
set terminal epslatex enhanced 
set output 'nfn.tex' 
unset key

set border 3
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror

set format $g$
set format x "%2.0f" 
set format y "%2.0f" 

u(x)=m*x+b
fit u(x) "nfn.dat" using 1:2 via m,b

set xzeroaxis linestyle 2 lt 2 lc 9
set xlabel "Applied Current mA" 

set ylabel "Voltage {$mV$}" offset -3.0 

set xrange [ -15.00 : 15.00 ]
set yrange [ -3.0 : 3.0 ]

plot  u(x), 'nfn.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with xyerrorbars

TOEND
```

Yes the file exists.
these are the packages I have added:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress,square]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage[justification=justified,indention=40pt]{caption}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Some of them are not really relevant but I don't know if there is a conflict causing it. I reinstalled all my packages and that didn't help either. It works fine until I try to use latex fonts and then come the problems.

Comment: why not use pgfplot with gnuplot and tikz? \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis} \addplot+[only marks] 
   gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{  
        plot 'Data.txt' ;            
             };\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: I tried this before but I have a lot of graphs to make so I was hoping to use one script to write them all. The error bars were quite confusing on pgfplots too,

Answer (score 4):

Your gnuplot script creates files called `nfn.tex` and `nfn.eps`. In your LaTeX code you are trying to load `npn.eps` and `npn.tex` (i.e. you use *p* instead of *f*).